# Wake from sleep Kernel Panic: -- "Could not read LR" -- What is LR?

Tags: kernel-panic

When I try and understand this Kernel Panic Report, But I don't know what **LR** is. What is **LR**?  How can I tell if this is a hardware problem or software?

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800a79b0d4): launchd exited (signal 9, exit status 0 CS_KILLED)

uuid info:
0x7fff6dc7e000  uuid = <a468d85e-d8d6-3461-8c99-49d3b9acfc63>
0x10e779000 uuid = <48362449-4519-317e-9a8b-7524036de5ea>

Thread 3 crashed

RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x00007fff6dcbe5f8, RCX: 0x000000010e779a00, RDX: 0x000000010e7c17b8
RSP: 0x0000700000080650, RBP: 0x00007000000806d0, RSI: 0x00000000000001b1, RDI: 0x00007fff6dcbe5f8
R8:  0x00007fff94871119, R9:  0x0000700000080a40, R10: 0x000000000015be00, R11: 0x000000010e7b9170
R12: 0x00007fdb8147ddb0, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x000000010e7bf831
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0x00007fff6dc984d0, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff8015913b60
    0x00007fff985c5dcd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 1: 0xffffff8015ac3000
      Could not read LR from frame at 0x0000700000116d48    <--------------Error

Thread 2: 0xffffff8015c43db0
    0x00007fff985d47b5
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 3: 0xffffff801b40a6d0
    0x00007fff6dc82063
    0x00007fff94871262
    0x000000010e7b9170
    0x000000010e78a4a0
    0x000000010e78eb95
    0x00007fff985c040b
    0x00007fff985d0675
    0x00007fff985c4a83
    0x00007fff985c5200
    0x00007fff985cb707
    0x00007fff985c3d53
    0x00007fff985c3b00
    0x00007fff89dab4de
    0x00007fff89da9341
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 4: 0xffffff8021758920
    0x000000010e7a447f
    0x00007fff985d8324
    0x00007fff985c040b
    0x00007fff985c503b
    0x00007fff985cb707
    0x00007fff985c3d53
    0x00007fff985c3b00
    0x00007fff89dab4de
    0x00007fff89da9341
    0x0000000000000000

Mac OS version: 15F34
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 15.5.0: Tue Apr 19 18:36:36 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.50.21~8/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7E7B0822-D2DE-3B39-A7A5-77B40A668BC6
System model name: MacBookAir5,2 (Mac-2E6FAB96566FE58C)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LR** is a Link Register.

> A link register is a special-purpose register which holds the address to return to when a function call completes.

More info on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_register).

Crash occured on Thread 3 and it's not related to the LR. It's hard to tell what happened since the report is not symbolicated.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what LR is.   I don't see any way to symbolicate a kernel panic unless I work for apple?   https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24772